# How to pass slug as url in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass slug in the Url, but I am unable to do so.
The slug is in the form like if have a text:-
text: - This is Stackoverflow
slug:- this-is-stackoverflow
but I am unable to achieve this. 
my model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class EmailTemplates(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    subject = models.CharField(db_column="subject",max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(db_column="slug",unique=True, max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(db_column="content", help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt',auto_now=True, help_text="")
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt',auto_now=True, help_text="")
    updatedBy = models.IntegerField(db_column='updatedBy',  help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'email_templates'
```

my url i am trying is:-

```
url(r'^email/edit/(?P<email_template_id>[\w-]+)/$', email_managment.email_send, name='email-edit')
```

my views is like that:-

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def email_send(request,email_template_id):
    try:
        form = emailTemplates(request.POST or None)
        edit_email_end = 'add'
        email_template_obj = {}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                subject = request.POST.get('subject')
                lowercase = subject.lower()
                slug = lowercase.replace(" ","-")
                print slug
                content = request.POST.get('content')
                if email_template_id is None or email_template_id == '':
                    add_email_template_entry = EmailTemplates(subject=subject, content=content,slug=slug)
                    add_email_template_entry.save(using="cms")
                    messages.success(request, 'Successfully added to the email template  page')
                elif email_template_id:
                    email_template_obj = EmailTemplates.objects.using("cms").get(id=email_template_id)
                    email_template_obj.subject = subject
                    email_template_obj.content = content
                    email_template_obj.slug = slug
                    email_template_obj.save(using="cms")
                    messages.success(request, 'Successfully update to the email templates')
                return redirect('cms:email-list')

        if email_template_id is not None:
            edit_email_end = 'edit'
            email_template_obj = EmailTemplates.objects.using("cms").get(id=email_template_id)
        return render(request, 'templates/email_managment/add_email.html',{
            'edit_email_end': edit_email_end,'email_template_obj':email_template_obj})
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        raise Http404
```

the error which is comming is

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello-took-of-fools'

Please ignore gramatical mistakes if there any.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, you are unable to pass the slug? How have you tried? What happened when you did? What error did you get?

Comment: error:-invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello-took-of-fools'

Comment: You need to show the full traceback, so we know where that error is coming from. You should also show your models.

Comment: i have share my model and that is the only error i am getting

Comment: Because you are purposely hiding the rest of the error with that pointless try/except block. Remove that and let Django show you the full error.

Comment: "GET /email/list HTTP/1.1" 200 15512
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello-took-of-fools'
Not Found: /email/edit/hello-took-of-fools/ "GET /email/edit/hello-took-of-fools/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1744

Comment: after removing try/except no change

Comment: After removing the try/except you will get the full traceback in your browser, assuming you have DEBUG=True.

Answer (score 0):

Because you won't show the full error, we have to guess what is happening.

There is one obvious thing you are doing wrong. Even though you refer to the parameter you are passing as `email_template_id`, it's not an ID, it's a slug. But when you query the model, you query by ID rather than by slug.

In both places where you do `EmailTemplates.objects.get()`, you should have `slug=email_template_id` rather than `id=...`. If you called your parameter what it actually is - a slug rather than an id - this would be more obvious.

(Note also, your model form can be made to update an existing object as well as create a new one, if you just pass in the object as the `instance` parameter to your form instantiation. That would make you first `else` block unnecessary. But even if you choose not to do that, you should *always* get the data from `form.cleaned_data` rather than directly from `request.POST`.)